# Graph: Creating shortest marked path to connect two nodes

Tags: graph-algorithm

Given an undirected, unweighted graph in which some nodes are marked, is there an efficient way to find the unmarked nodes between node A and B which would create a "marked" path from A to B when they are marked? The number of those "bridge" nodes should be minimal.

For example, in the graph below there would be two minimal ways to connect node A to B. One possibility would be to mark the node labelled 1, the other possibility would be to mark node 2.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your graph into a directed, weighted graph such that:

- the weight of each edge going into a **marked** node is set to 0
- the weight of each edge going into an **unmarked** node is 1

Find all lowest-cost paths from A to B.

Comment: And then using dijkstra, right? Thanks, I had that idea a few days ago too.